# How to say "Invalid Response" Choose Again? (In Java)

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I want the user to choose i or c. What do I do if they do not? How do I make them answer the question?

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: Your questions is unclear.

Comment: You check the input, and exit the loop only if it is correct. Post an [MCVE] to show what you tried.

Comment: `System.out.println("Please press I or C");`

Comment: I'm asking how I do a while loop to make them choose I or c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below:

```
while(true) {
  System.out.println("Please enter I or C or E for Exit");
  String input = sc.nextLine();
  if("I".equals(input)) {
       //perform operation 
       break; 
      }
  else if("C".equals(input)) { 
       //perform operation
        break;
     }
  else if("E".equals(input)){
        break;
    }
  System.out.println("Please Enter the correct option");           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hop my solution help you solve your problem, your solution is given below.

package iron;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Selection {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please enter i or c .");
    while (true){
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    String result=scan.nextLine();
    if (!(result.equalsIgnoreCase("c")||result.equalsIgnoreCase("i"))){
        System.out.println("Please enter i or c");
    }
    else{
    System.out.println("you have entered i or c");
    break;
    }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Simply we can do it with switch statement as below:

```
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
Char a=s.next();
Switch(a)
{
case 'I':
//operation
break;
case 'C':
//operation
break;
default:
System.out.println("Please choose either I or C");
}
```